How to find all fk references to a table in postgres, in a tree format
I am working on writing integrated tests on a postgres DB, and i need to create rows in that, while creating a table, how can i list or visualize all the fk relationships till the deepest level?
Currently, i am looking at the ddl of a table and then ddls of the tables where the original table has a fk reference and so on.
I believe there has to be a simpler/easier process to find this info.

Are you perhaps looking for https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html or https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html ?

As suggested by @Richard Huxton, you can explore the relationships through pg_catalog.pg_constraint. If you start the psql client with -E switch, it'll show you that's exactly how it finds the links when you ask it to describe a table with \d meta-command.
Tables referenced by table public.t2:
SELECT conname, conrelid::pg_catalog.regclass AS ontable,
       pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(oid, true) AS condef
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint c
 WHERE confrelid IN (SELECT pg_catalog.pg_partition_ancestors('public.t2')
                     UNION ALL VALUES ('public.t2'::regclass))
       AND contype = 'f' AND conparentid = 0
ORDER BY conname;

Tables referencing table public.t2:
SELECT true as sametable, conname,
  pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(r.oid, true) as condef,
  conrelid::pg_catalog.regclass AS ontable
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint r
WHERE r.conrelid = 'public.t2'::regclass AND r.contype = 'f'
     AND conparentid = 0
ORDER BY conname;

You can use PL/pgSQL with dynamic SQL statements or a recursive CTE to run through the links and give you a complete tree of what your target table's related to, directly or indirectly.

If you mean an Entity Relationship diagram to help you see all the links between your target table and anything it's related to, DBeaver (you tagged) has them, on the rightmost tab of the Database Object Editor:


My other guess would be you're looking for a way to have the tool automatically create a template insert statement to populate a specific target table as well as all tables it's supposed to be linked with - I don't think there's a feature for that. Both the SQL generator and mock data generator features only seem to target the specific table you select as the target, without trying to also populate any related ones.

The mock data generator can pull some existing identifiers to populate an FK in your target, but it won't generate that row in the linked table beforehand.

